# How to write an R function to pivot the last n minutes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have per-minute data that looks like this, with 30 different unique IDs. Each row contains the per-minute measurement, and a value of 1 if the measurement was verified by a technician.

| ID | dttm | Measurement | Verified? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:00 | 89 | 1 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:01 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:02 | 96 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:03 | 92 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:04 | 98 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:05 | 88 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:06 | 86 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:07 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:08 | 94 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:09 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:10 | 81 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:11 | 82 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:12 | 95 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:13 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:14 | 87 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:15 | 91 | 1 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:16 | 89 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:17 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:18 | 96 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:19 | 92 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:20 | 98 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:21 | 88 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:22 | 86 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:23 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:24 | 94 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:25 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:26 | 81 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:27 | 82 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:28 | 95 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:29 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:30 | 87 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:31 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:32 | 89 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:33 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:34 | 96 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:35 | 92 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:36 | 98 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:37 | 88 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:38 | 86 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:39 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:40 | 94 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:41 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:42 | 81 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:43 | 82 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:44 | 95 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:45 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:46 | 87 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:47 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:48 | 89 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:49 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:50 | 96 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:51 | 92 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:52 | 98 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:53 | 88 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:54 | 86 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:55 | 91 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:56 | 94 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:57 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:58 | 81 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 08:59 | 82 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 09:00 | 95 | 1 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 09:01 | 90 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 09:02 | 87 | 0 |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 09:03 | 91 | 0 |

And so on, for a total of 2880 minutes per ID.

What I am looking to achieve is to pivot the previous 59 minutes around verified values so that there is a column for each of the preceding 59 minutes.

For example, since there are 59 minutes preceeding the value at 1-1-2023 09:00 for ID 1, the result would be:

| ID | Verified_Time | min_1 | min_2 | min_3 | min_4 | min_5 | min_6 | min_7 | min_8 | ... | min_59 | verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2023 09:00 | 90 | 96 | 92 | 98 | 88 | 86 | 91 | 94 | ... | 82 | 95 |

I understand how to do a simple pivot wider around a column, but I am not sure how to pivot if the value is verified and there are 59 preceeding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know how to `pivot_wider` around a column, we only need to construct something like a list whose entries are the subsets of the data around the relevant dates.

The relevant dates are those who are verified and have 59 preceding values inside `df`. They can be obtained by the following. In my example I used your data and additionally set the date at `09:02` as verified.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(
    `Verified?` == 1 &
      dttm - as.difftime(59, units = "mins") > min(dttm),
    .by = ID
  ) |>
  pull(dttm)

# [1] "2023-01-01 09:00:00 CET" "2023-01-01 09:02:00 CET"
```

For such a `VerifiedDate`, the relevant data subset can be obtained by

```
df |> filter(between(
  dttm,
  VerifiedDate - as.difftime(59, units = "mins"),
  VerifiedDate
))
```

Putting it together using `purrr::map` yields the desired list of dataframes. On each of the dataframes you can now use pivoting in order to get the desired output.

```
purrr::map(df |>
             filter(
               `Verified?` == 1 &
                 dttm - as.difftime(59, units = "mins") > min(dttm),
               .by = ID
             ) |>
             pull(dttm)
           , function (VerifiedDate) {
             df |> filter(between(
               dttm,
               VerifiedDate - as.difftime(59, units = "mins"),
               VerifiedDate
             ))
           })

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 60 × 4
#      ID dttm                Measurement `Verified?`
#   <int> <dttm>                    <int>       <int>
# 1     1 2023-01-01 08:01:00          90           0

...

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 60 × 4
#      ID dttm                Measurement `Verified?`
#   <int> <dttm>                    <int>       <int>
# 1     1 2023-01-01 08:03:00          92           0
```

Used data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), dttm = structure(c(1672556400, 1672556460, 
1672556520, 1672556580, 1672556640, 1672556700, 1672556760, 1672556820, 
1672556880, 1672556940, 1672557000, 1672557060, 1672557120, 1672557180, 
1672557240, 1672557300, 1672557360, 1672557420, 1672557480, 1672557540, 
1672557600, 1672557660, 1672557720, 1672557780, 1672557840, 1672557900, 
1672557960, 1672558020, 1672558080, 1672558140, 1672558200, 1672558260, 
1672558320, 1672558380, 1672558440, 1672558500, 1672558560, 1672558620, 
1672558680, 1672558740, 1672558800, 1672558860, 1672558920, 1672558980, 
1672559040, 1672559100, 1672559160, 1672559220, 1672559280, 1672559340, 
1672559400, 1672559460, 1672559520, 1672559580, 1672559640, 1672559700, 
1672559760, 1672559820, 1672559880, 1672559940, 1672560000, 1672560060, 
1672560120, 1672560180), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Measurement = c(89L, 90L, 96L, 92L, 98L, 88L, 86L, 91L, 94L, 
    100L, 81L, 82L, 95L, 90L, 87L, 91L, 89L, 90L, 96L, 92L, 98L, 
    88L, 86L, 91L, 94L, 100L, 81L, 82L, 95L, 90L, 87L, 91L, 89L, 
    90L, 96L, 92L, 98L, 88L, 86L, 91L, 94L, 100L, 81L, 82L, 95L, 
    90L, 87L, 91L, 89L, 90L, 96L, 92L, 98L, 88L, 86L, 91L, 94L, 
    100L, 81L, 82L, 95L, 90L, 87L, 91L), `Verified?` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```